# Loading data to Dropdown from multiple text files

Tags: jquery, file, dropdown

I have some text files such as `s1.text,s2.text,s3.text`. They include the following information.

s1.text:

```
<option value='val11'>text11</option>
<option value='val12'>text12</option>
```

s2.text:

```
<option value='val21'>text21</option>
<option value='val22'>text22</option>
```

s3.text:

```
<option value='val31'>text31</option>
<option value='val32'>text32</option>
```

How can I load them into my `crsdd` downdown list? I can load a single file by `$('#crsdd').load("s1.txt");` but when I have multiple files, I **cannot** handle it.

I want the out put of the following.

```
<select id='crsdd' name='crs'>
  <option value='val11'>text11</option>
  <option value='val12'>text12</option>
  <option value='val21'>text21</option>
  <option value='val22'>text22</option>
  <option value='val31'>text31</option>
  <option value='val32'>text32</option>
</select>
```

See the example here.
[Switching depending on Dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988072/switching-depending-on-dropdown-option/35988376)

Answer (score 1):

Well, a quick solution is loading the files synchronously and then composing your dropdown option.

E.g.

```
var array_of_files = ["s1.text","s2.text","s3.text"];//if you need these files dynamically , i.e. from lets say a set of other options, compose this dynamically

//when you need to load these files together -
var docLoader = function(index){
    $.get(array_of_files[index],function(data){//get data and append it to your select box
        $('#crsdd').append(data);
        if(index < array_of_files.length){
            docLoader(index+1);//Call itself with new index
        }
    });
}
docLoader(0);//call the loader with index 0
```

This should work!

Comment: I wrote it in a `switch` and could **not** make it work.